# Confusion regarding DOM manipulation in VueJs

Tags: vuejs2

I have a select element in my template and I'm calling a function with @change.

```
<select 
  @change="updatePriorityAndStatus($event, windex, w.ProjectCode)">
 </select>
```

As you can see I'm using the $event variable to access the DOM event.
Now inside my function if I do something likes this

```
updatePriorityAndStatus($event, id, code) {
      $event.target.parentNode.children[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ff3300';
    },
```

Does it manipulate the actual DOM ?
As we know we are not supposed to manipulate the actual DOM like we do in JS or JQuery.

Comment: `$event` gives you access to native DOM event, and yes what you are doing in that method would be called as anti-pattern.

Comment: you can use dynamic classes for this which is more idiomatic to vue, check them out in the docs.